# How to replace a string when another string is found in a line?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, grep

I want to replace a string 'xy' with another string 'ab' when string 'ny' is found in a line of a unix file.

Sample text:

```
If we have xy today we can go to ny.
If we have xy tomorrow we can go to ny tomorrow.
If we have mn now we can go to ny now.
```

Output text should look like:-

```
If we have ab today we can go to ny.
If we have ab tomorrow we can go to ny tomorrow.
If we have mn now we can go to ny now.
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is very easy to do.

Comment: @G-Man We don't have a sample of the file but if he just wants to replace a string on lines where anther appears then he can just use `grep` to print the lines where `ny` appears and then use `sed` to replace `xy` with `ab`.

Comment: ISTM that the question that that answers is a rather twisted interpretation of the question that the OP asked. The output would be ***a subset of*** the input file, with the desired changes made in those lines.

Comment: @G-man What it seems to you could also be entirely different than what is being asked because he hasn't provided a sample of the contents of the file or the expected output. Until we have that, all we can go on its what we think is wanted which is why I haven't posted an answer.

Comment: satyaki: You have given an example for the question "I want to replace a string 'xy' with another string 'ab' in every line of a file."   Since the string 'ny' is found in every line of your input, you aren't demonstrating what's supposed to happen with lines that don't contain it.

Comment: @G-Man I have added a sample input and output text. The discussion in this thread is quite helpful as well. Thanks all.

Comment: @satyaki The crucial line that you are missing is when you *don't* have `ny`, but *do* have `xy`.

Comment: @Sparhawk In that case, the line remains in its original state, nothing changes, since ny is not there.

Comment: @satyaki Yes, that was my interpretation, but you might as well put this line in your example.

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is probably the simplest approach:

```
sed '/ny/s/xy/ab/g' file
```

It contains two sub-commands: `/ny/` searches for a pattern, and `s/xy/ab/g` does actual substitution. Notice that it will replace all occurrences of `xy`; if you want to replace only first of them in each line just remove final `g`.

Comment: Nice +1. Much simpler than awk.

Comment: Strictly speaking `/ny/` is not a command but the address for the following `s` command (this could also have been a line number or a range of lines between two regular expressions or numbers).

Answer (score 2):

An answer in `awk`:

```
awk '/ny/ {gsub(/xy/,"ab")}; {print}' test.txt
```

### Explanation

- `/ny/`: only do the following commands when there is `ny` on the line.
- `gsub(/xy/,"ab")`: substitute `/xy/` with `ab`, only on those lines.
- `{print}`: regardless of what line you are on, print the line.